# How to solve invalid read in C

Tags: c, realloc

I'm having an invalid read issue with my program, I'm creating a simple shell in c which support history and it's built-ins. Here's my problem I have a variable

```
 char *cmd = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
```

Wen I run the command `^p^l^`, now `cmd = ^p^l^`, I pass `cmd` to a search function that searches through history and return a match or the same string. `ft_man_search_replace(&cmd, &pos, hist)`

```
void    ft_man_search_replace(char **cmd, int *pos, t_stack hist)
{
    char            **split;
    t_search_hist   search;
    int             i;

    // splits ^string^string^ into array
    split = ft_strsplit(*cmd + 1, '^');
    i = *pos;
    // get previous history and assign it to haystack
    search.haystack = ft_get_prev_hist(hist);
    search.needle = split[0];
    search.with = split[1];
    *cmd = ft_search_replace(search, 0, 0, 0);
     //if returned string is equal to *cmd, there was no match
     //assign *cmd to empty string.
    if (ft_strequ(search.haystack, *cmd))
    {
        ft_putendl("\n21sh: substitution failed");
        *cmd = "";
        *pos = 0;
        return ;
    }
    i = ft_strlen(*cmd);
    ft_cursor(*cmd, i + 1, &hist);
    *pos = i;
}
```

After running this function it's seems that `cmd` is no longer having memory allocation of `256`, when I type something I get invalid read my guess is that I'm reaching the end of the string. e.g if the match was not found I assign `*cmd = ""`, now if I try to modify `cmd` I get invalid read. How can I solve this? I tried reallocating using the below function, as I'm not allowed to use `realloc`.

```
void    *ft_realloc(void *ptr, size_t len)
{
    void    *real;

    real = (void *)malloc(len);
    if (real)
    {
        memset(real, 0, len);
        memcpy(real, ptr, strlen(ptr));
    }
    free(ptr);
    return (real);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you saying you're doing `free("")`? Because yes, that would obviously cause issues.

Comment: Casting `malloc()` to `(void *)` makes no sense. If you did this to avoid compiler warnings, your code has bigger problems. Did you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: No,the libraries are there, Sorry I can't post a working example the code is too long and has many functions.

Comment: BTW `memcpy(real, ptr, strlen(ptr));  memset(real, 0, len);` --> `memset(real, 0, len);memcpy(real, ptr, strlen(ptr));`

Comment: @TenTenPeter That's why you're supposed to reduce it before posting. By removing all the irrelevant parts you'll either discover the problem yourself or you'll end up with a much more focused question.

Comment: if the returned value from `*cmd = ft_search_replace(search, 0, 0, 0);` is `hello` and I try to edit it to `hello world` this's where I get invalid read, even though `cmd` was allocated `256`.

Comment: @user3121023 so I need to free `cmd` and reallocate memory again?

Comment: @user3121023 what about `strcpy` instead of `=` I think it might solve the problem without discarding memory allocation.

Comment: A couple of stylistic comments: `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, so multiplying by it is never necessary. And in C code, you should not cast the return value of `malloc`, and in particular `(void *)malloc(…)` is completely pointless since the type is already `void *`.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have managed to solve the issue, as [user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023) pointed out that `*cmd =` will discard the memory allocation, I decided to use `strcpy` and `memset` instead of `=`.

```
//libraries here
# define SIZE 256   

char *cmd = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);

void    ft_man_search_replace(char **cmd, int *pos, t_stack hist)
{
    char            **split;
    t_search_hist   search;
    int             i;

    // splits ^string^string^ into array
    split = ft_strsplit(*cmd + 1, '^');
    i = *pos;
    // get previous history and assign it to haystack
    search.haystack = ft_get_prev_hist(hist);
    search.needle = split[0];
    search.with = split[1];
    memset(*cmd, 0, SIZE);
    strcpy(*cmd, ft_search_replace(search, 0, 0, 0));
     //if returned string is equal to *cmd, there was no match
     //assign *cmd to empty string.
    if (ft_strequ(search.haystack, *cmd))
    {
        ft_putendl("\n21sh: substitution failed");
        memset(*cmd, 0, SIZE);
        strcpy(*cmd, "");
        *pos = 0;
        return ;
    }
    i = ft_strlen(*cmd);
    ft_cursor(*cmd, i + 1, &hist);
    *pos = i;
}
```